# How to enable ajax request in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Someone please explain me how do I send ajax request to enable ajax in my application. In my controller I have this code in the respond_to block

```
 format.html {  }
 format.xml  {  }
 format.js {}
```

Normally .html response is always sent back to the user. But I want to know how can I enable .xml or .js and how this works.

Comment: Check here the response of method with js format

[Ajax with rails][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737026/how-remote-true-works-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Rails Guides on [Working with Javascript in Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#server-side-concerns). The linked to section should be particularly helpful in understanding this problem.