# How does ':remote => true' works in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand how `:remote => true` works in rails. I know that when I write it an ajax request is sent and the `.js` response is made. But how does this work? I mean, where does the action go, etc.?

Comment: Inspect the form element in the rendered HTML in the browser, look at the `action` attribute. Its same as a regular, non-ajax, request; whichever Controller#action is set up to respond to that URL is where the action will go.

Comment: `remote: true` is really just telling the browser to not refresh the page. Do the action that you would normally do, but don't do anything to the page.

Comment: Here is a good reference that helps break things down: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

Comment: Can you tell me where can I find 10 things that occur when I write :remote? Everywhere I find is that it enable ajax response.

Comment: That's what it does... it enables ajax response. `data-remote='true'`

Comment: @user1478137 It is starting to sound like you're asking us to do your work / research for you. Admittedly, off the top of my head, I'd have to think hard to come up with 10 things that occur when you do `:remote=>true`, but the only way you're going to figure that out is research and read read read. Best place to start, I think, is the [Rails documentation on working with javascript in rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) (which deals with ajax and forms).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let me explain the whole flow of AJAX-Rails and `remote => true`.

First, when you add `remote => true` to the form it will submit or call the action which you have defined in the form.

Here is an example:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'my', :action => 'my_data'}, :id => 'filter_form', :remote => true) do %>
  #code here
  <%= submit_tag 'save', :name => 'commit' %>
<% end %>
```

Now, the above code will go to `my_data` action in `my` controller.

Here you can define the response type with:

```
def my_data
  #actions on data here
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Now you have to make a "`.js`" file with the same name as the action:

```
my_data.js.erb
```

This "`.js`" file will handle the form. You could write and update document elements through jQuery and JavaScript.

Comment: thanks man, I already implemented this before but forgot the details about naming file by controller action name

Comment: Now you can also use `form_with` which by default makes the form `remote: true`. Here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form

Comment: Rails 5.1 introduced `form_with`, with remote forms, confusingly, this has changed in Rails 6.1 where the default is now local and you get remote by setting `local: false`. https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_with

Comment: Apparently `remote:` has been removed as of Rails 7 and `local: false` works.